# Null Hypothesis P-value Interpretation

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I do a two sample comparison with alpha = 0.05. The p-value I get is 0.33. I know that we do not reject the null hypothesis because it greater than 0.05. My question is can I interpret that the 0.33 is the probability that my null hypothesis is true. Could I also say that the null hypothesis probability of being false is 0.67?

Comment: See the ASA statement on statistical significance and p-values: https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108#_i30 : Principle 2: "P-values do not measure the probability that the studied hypothesis is true, or the probability that the data were produced by random chance alone."

Comment: Thank you very much Glen. That link explained everything.